# FCM Firebase push notification Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using `FCM` to send notifications for a project in booth plattforms, `iOS` and `Android`. Following are the `payloads` I'm sending:

```
{ 
  "to":"user_key",
  "priority":"high",
  "content_available":true,
  "mutable_content":true,
  "data":{
        "body":"test"
  }
}
```

After reading the `Firebase` documentation, the behaviour when sending `notification` and `data payload` through `FCM` is:

**iOS**

- You won't see banner if `notification` -> `body` is not defined.

**Android**

- If you pass `data payload` only, it will receive data when is in `background`.
- If you pass `notification_payload`, `system tray` will handle it.

The thing is:

For `Android` I want to avoid to pass `notification_payload` in order to receive data when app is in background (in this way onMessageReceived() will be called). But then, I won´t receive `notifications` in `iOS`.

Help/Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Server should use different json structures for IOS and Android push request. For example:

**Android:**

```
[data] => Array
        (
            [title] => Test
            [message] => Message
        )
```

**IOS:**

```
[notification] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title
            [body] => Body
            [sound] => 1
            [vibrate] => 1
        )

[data] => Array
        (
            [custom_key] => custom_value
        )
```

You can edit it according to your task.

Comment: I'm using  Firebase Cloud Messaging, can't handle that.

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify. Are you just testing in the firebase console for sending notifications?

Comment: I have a project in both platforms, Android and iOS. I'm implementing Firebase push notifications for booth projects. Question edited.

Comment: Understood, but someone should execute the sending of push notification into mobile platforms. For example, API? Where does the sending process begin?

Comment: DOCU: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref?hl=en-419 , API: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Comment: It`s just http/s request. Who will execute it?

Comment: It's implemented on each project. On Android for example, I use OkHttpClient.

Comment: So, it means that you execute the request. It means that you can send requests on fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send with different json body for IOS and Android according to your task.

Comment: Yes, I can. But how should be this json bodies to implement what I want? I have tried what documentation says but I can find the right solution.